# Wake up my app upon FCM notification on Android Oreo and higher

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process, android-8.0-oreo, wakeup

My app is for an important part dealing with Instant Messaging and receives FCM notifications. How can the app wake up for a few seconds upon reception of a High Importance notification, do a short fetch from the server and go back to its previous state. I have seen a lot of theoretical explanations but no real example of source code to achieve that. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

1. Extend *FirebaseMessagingService* and get the message payload in
   *onMessageReceived*.  (basic JSON parsing)
2. Then, schedule a job to be executed instantly using [**Firebase JobDispatcher**](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) (code to schedule is in the repo itself) or the new [**WorkManager**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).
3. Call the network request from the job.

Comment: Thanks. I tried JobDispatcher and experienced some troubles, but it worked just fine with WorkManager. Hoping that the current version is stable.